# Годов или лет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

2011/2012 и 2012/2013 учебных годов или лет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Учебных годов.**
"Учебный год" — устойчивое выражение, означающее, как известно, иной, нежели календарный год, промежуток времени. Так как выражение устойчивое, мы не можем менять слово "годов" на слово "лет", которое имеет значение "промежуток времени  в 365 дней".
***Итак,* 2011 - 2012 и 2012 - 2013 учебных годов.**

Comment: **Итак, 2011 - 2012 учебных годов.** 

Здесь будет 2011–2012 учебный год (в ед. числе и без пробелов вокруг короткого тире).

Comment: Здесь будет "2011/2012 и 2012/2013 учебных годов". Как автор спрашивал.

Comment: Да, верно. Но после "Итак..." идет именно то, что я уточнила )

Comment: Я понял.   
Вы обратили внимание, что в ответ слегка ушел от вопроса. )

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы. Исправила, добавила.

Answer (score 1):

Годов.
Учебных или каких еще - абсолютно без разницы и  устойчивось выражения абсолютно ни при чем.
"Лет" используется как счетная форма только для **количественных** числительных: **на протяжении шестидесяти лет**, но **на протяжении 60-х годов**.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы правильно ответить , нужно уточнить для себя, что имеется в виду -  период времени, как абстрактное понятие, или период времени, как конкретное понятие.К примеру: На протяжении нескольких лет. И: В течении 2011-2012 и 2012-2013 учебных годов